# Facebook Graph API v2.1: getting user id and his posts

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Imagine the situation when I'm logged in facebook web application as userA. I know userB's nickname but he is not in my friendlist and I do not know his id. And, of course, he does not use my app.

1. How can I get userB's id via a nickname?
2. After that how can I get his wall posts?

Are there any specific permissions? May be there are manual pages I've missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In v1.0, the following was possible:

`http://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/{user-name}`

However, with v2.0 and v2.1, accessing users via IDs or Usernames not connected to your application is not possible. E.g., trying `http://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/{user-name}` will throw an error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (user-name)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

Using the new PHP SDK (v4.0.x) you can do the following:

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '{user-name}', array(), 'v1.0' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if I add version string to my API call, I'm not sure it will still work after [April 30th, 2015](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog). If I try to access user vie its global id I get error message _"The global ID <user-id> is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead."_. How can I get mentioned application specific id for user with global ID <user-id>?

Comment: Yes, v1.0 calls will stop working after April 30th 2015. You can't get application specific ID unless the user has authorised your app.

Comment: Is it possible to call API v1.0 via newest facebook PHP SDK?

Comment: Yes, the fifth parameter can be used to specify a version, e.g.:
`$response = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', $data, 'v1.0' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();`