# graph.facebook.com/username does not work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, web-scraping

I tried to get user detail using https://graph.facebook.com/username . But it throws an error

```
    "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (ramesh.randika.56)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
```

does anybody have  a solution for this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API v2.1: getting user id and his posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258670/facebook-graph-api-v2-1-getting-user-id-and-his-posts)

Comment: It says it right there already: _Cannot query users by their username_ The field `username` was removed with API v2 – your app is _not supposed_ to get information about arbitrary users any more.

Comment: @cygery He can't use the suggested solution anymore, because v1.0 is gone.

Comment: @cygery not a duplicate. I just want to try this on my browser   


        
    https://graph.facebook.com/username/picture?width=800

Comment: @ramesh This doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 9):

graph.facebook.com/{Username} is not avaiable now but [lookup-id.com](https://lookup-id.com) still can find your facebook ID, facebook group ID and facebook page ID

Comment: Any Idea how does this website works as now the API support support has been withdrawn?

Comment: When I try that site I get: "Unable to lookup. Note that the system just response for Open Group".

So it seems that they have cached data if you looked it up before but if you look up something new they have no idea what the id is.

Comment: @WizKid sometimes i receive it too then i try again it is ok

Answer (score 7):

"View page source" Option in every web browser will help you.
Follow this-

1. Open the timeline of that person/FB account.
2. **Right-click** anywhere on the web-page->**View page Source**-> wait 1 or 2 seconds to load the new page.
3. **Press Ctrl+f** (used to find any string,word in the page) then type " **profile_id=** " (without quotes).
4. Copy the **long number** after " = ", .

Conclusion : Using the "username" doesn't work anymore (Updated till Oct 2018),**profile_id** is the thing u needed instead.

Answer (score 3):

The `username` field was removed with the introduction of the Graph API v2.0.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

> `/me/username` is no longer available.

Comment: All applications currently get switched to v2.0, and there's nothing you can do about it. It's not coming back.

Comment: @Tobi Just out of curiosity, I wanted to know even after the API support was discontinued how can lookup-id.com work?

Comment: http://lookup-id.com/ no longer works. At least for all the profile urls I tried.

Comment: you can try with findmyfbid.com - seems working for me