# Add Facebook Profile Picture to an email signature

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, html-email

I'm trying to make an email signature using HTML for someone. What she wants is to automatically pull out her profile pic in Facebook. So every time she changes her picture in Facebook, she doesn't need to change it in her email signature.

After researching, I found out that I can use http://graph.facebook.com/username/picture to get her picture in Facebook. I have tried using http://graph.facebook.com a couple of weeks ago and it's working but now it's not. Here is the result after trying http://graph.facebook.com/username/picture

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: username",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

So I googled again and saw this [graph.facebook.com/username does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868201/graph-facebook-com-username-does-not-work)

So my question, is there an alternative besides http://graph.facebook.com/username/picture?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the user id instead of the username. Either the global user id, or an app-scoped one. As for how to get it – please research.

Comment: @CBroe Even if I use the user id, it doesn't work. All I get is:
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}

Comment: http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture should get you Mark Zuckerberg’s profile picture, without requiring any access token.