# How to implement PHP Facebook login for php 5.3 version?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Anyone know how I can implement Facebook login for PHP version 5.3. Since the PHP Facebook SDK version only supports PHP 5.4.

How I can implement this as we can't just change our project php version to PHP 5.4 as it may cause the breaking of the system.

I found the below link for php 5.3 version support facebook sdk but it didn't work for me as it through the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Cannot query users by
>   their username (james) thrown in
>   /code/test/mywebsite/public/fb_login/Facebook/base_facebook.php on
>   line 1325 E_ERROR Error in file »base_facebook.php« at line 1325:
>   Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Cannot query users by their username
>   (james) thrown

The following is the link for php 5.3 facebook php sdk:
[facebook archive](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk)

Thanks.

Comment: You should not be using PHP 5.3, period. (Nor [any version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions) of PHP 5.x.) It [ceased to receive security updates in 2014](https://www.php.net/eol.php). The version of the Facebook SDK that worked with PHP 5.3 will definitely not work with the current versions of the Facebook API, either - it is irreparably outdated.

Comment: so is thr any other alternative ?

Comment: You need to set up a test server running PHP 7.x, test and make any necessary fixes, and transition to a modern version of the SDK.

Comment: humm not sure if we can migrate the whole system from PHP 5.3 to 7. As I think it would be easy to jump from 5.3 to 5.4 as hopefully that wont require lots of changes.

Comment: Anything in the 5.x line is dangerous to run in production. They have unpatched security holes.

Comment: Use Facebooks "PHP Graph SDK", this should also work up to PHP v7.0/7.1/7.2
https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk

Comment: @CodyKL The latest version that SDK explicitly supports is v2.10. The Facebook API is on v5. It's likely to not work on large portions of Facebook's current API.

Comment: in addition to the important comment that PHP 5.x is highly outdated: "Cannot query users by their username" - it is not possible with the API anymore, no matter which PHP version you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [graph.facebook.com/username does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868201/graph-facebook-com-username-does-not-work)

Comment: Thank you all and now we are trying to upgrade our php version from 5.3 to 5.4 and onwards. I know that its long way to go but at least we can try as it's really large system to do migration while it's highly used by the users.